# Record data from mobile phone's audio jack

Tags: android, audio, record

I am trying to record data from my mobile phone's audio interface. I used audiorecord function. Following is my code:

public void Initialize() {

```
buffersizebytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPPERSEC,channelConfiguration, audioEncoding); // 4096 on ion
buffer = new short[buffersizebytes];
buflen = buffersizebytes / 2;
audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
        android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPPERSEC,
        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, buffersizebytes);
acquire();


for(int i=0; i<4096; i++) buffer[i]=1;
```

}

```
public void acquire() {
    try {
        audioRecord.startRecording();
        mSamplesRead = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffersizebytes);
        audioRecord.stop();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
    }
}
```

I want to put my acquired data into a buffer of 4096 bytes. But my program only put data into 1024 bytes. Also first 432 bytes also zeros. But I am sending data continuously. What could be the issue?

Comment: I can't understand this line: `for(int i=0; i<4096; i++) buffer[i]=1;`

Comment: Neither why you don't use buflen instead of 4096.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMinBufferSize`, as the name implies gives you the *minimum* buffer size. You can set anything bigger, including 4096.

As for the first samples after initialization, my phone gives two gigantic peaks that last for about 0.5 seconds, so I guess it is caused by the recorder starting up. Try skipping a few samples (let's say 500) before processing real data.

Furthermore, the size of `buffer` should be `buffersizebytes/2`.